# How to edit the main form in C# from a timer?

Tags: c#, timer, delegates

I'm trying to display an error on my form and use timer to remove the error in a second.  I have:

```
const string sendingError = "currently sending a message please wait";
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
commandValues.errorList[sendingError] = sendingError;
commandValues.updateErrorList();
```

this functions as it should by updating a label with the error message

```
timer.Elapsed += ((source, e) => 
{
    var INDEX = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.IndexOfKey("errorBox");
    Debug.WriteLine(Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX]);
    Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX].Text = "";
    Debug.WriteLine("2" + Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX]);
});

timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
```

the debug line displays

```
1System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: currently sending a message please wait
1System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: currently sending a message please wait
1System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: currently sending a message please wait
1System.Windows.Forms.Label, Text: currently sending a message please wait
// etcetera
```

As you can see, the second debug line is never displaying.  Break points agree that it leaves the delegate when I try to change the label.

I'm new to C# so any advice would be appreciated, but specifically I would like to know how to have the main form edited after a timeout and why my attempt is failing.

Comment: Just use the right timer, specifically: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive I understand your problem, but it sounds like you're having an issue updating the UI from a background thread? If so, try this:

**timer.Start()** starts a new thread separate from your Winform's UI thread, so you may need to Invoke your WinForm's thread in order to see the changes.

```
timer.Elapsed += ((source, e) =>
{
    var INDEX = Form.ActiveForm.Controls.IndexOfKey("errorBox");
    Debug.WriteLine(Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX]);
    //Invoke the instance of "Form" to process changes on the UI thread
    Form.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX].Text = "";
    });
    Debug.WriteLine("2" + Form.ActiveForm.Controls[INDEX]);
});
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();
```

---

### **My thoughts on Invoking**

If WinForm and NOT Data Bound

```
myControl.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {/*update UI related values here*/});
```

or

```
myForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {/*update UI related values here*/});
```

If WinForm and Data Bound, you may need to update the UI by updating the databound property of your object, or invoke the databound object to update its own property (queueing **INotifyPropertyChange** or another similar Interface which will force refresh the UI). Note that refactoring your code to data-bind objects to your UI could also prove a permanent solution.

If XAML\WPF, you can use the following snippet to force update your XPF\XAML UI from the base application's dispatcher, like this:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((System.Action)delegate {/*update UI related values here*/});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should dispatch UI modifications from your `Timer thread` to `UI Thread`. Modifying UI elements from another threads is not allowed.

To do it you need to call `this.BeginInvoke`.

[How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: Avoid `BeginInvoke` over `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke` can lead to deadlock on the UI.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Backwards perhaps?  `Invoke` can deadlock, `BeginInvoke` can overwhelm the UI with a flood of messages, but can't deadlock.

Comment: Actually everything depends on how he's going to use it. Other threads always can lead to deadlocks with or without Invoke :-).

Comment: @BenVoigt No, I have it right. I just ran through this problem with one of my products, it would run for a few days (100% uptime app) and deadlock. Replacing all my BeginInvokes with Invoke resolved the issue, was due to many threads calling BeginInvoke at the same time, probably won't apply here but I avoid it now.

Comment: @RonBeyer That is not a deadlock, that is overwhelming the UI with a flood of messages, like Ben said.

Comment: @RonBeyer: (If it was a true deadlock) It wasn't `BeginInvoke` causing the deadlock, and you didn't resolve the issue, you just changed the timing enough to hide your race condition.